# Problema Importante con JavaScript al momento de cargar un html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Tengo un error al momemnto de cargar mi html, antes me habían dicho que era porque no declaraba el `id=modelo_card_curso"` pero ya lo hice y aún así me manda error

En la parte de abajo dejo el código html, js y la captura del error que me manda, no sé si es un error con Bootstrap o es un problema minimo

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    
  </head>

  <body>

    

    <div class="container-lg my-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-3" id="container modelo_card_curso">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="/imagenes_pagina/img-bootstrap.jpg" class="crop-image-course card-img-top" alt="##" >
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title hola">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
                        <p class="card-text line-clamp">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, fugiat. Accusamus veritatis nisi similique beatae totam, voluptatem blanditiis, numquam esse itaque facere quae nam magnam.
                        </p>
        
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mb-2 w-100">Ir a la clase </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning w-100">Archivos del curso </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>       

    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
var modelo_card_curso = document.getElementById("modelo_card_curso").innerHTML;
console.log(modelo_card_curso)
console.log("return 0")
```

cuando no está con `innerHTML` funciona bien, pero cuando lo agrego manda el error

```
var modelo_card_curso = document.getElementById("modelo_card_curso");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que el id `modelo_card_curso` no existe, por eso te devuelve `null`. Tu id es id="container modelo_card_curso".

Comment: En la línea `<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-3" id="container modelo_card_curso">` tienes que borrar la palabra `container` del `id` o sino al hacer el `getElementById` añadir esa palabra al id que escribas para que lo busque bien de manera que quede así `var modelo_card_curso = document.getElementById("container modelo_card_curso");`, pues arriba, en el html defines ese id y es el que tiene coincidir para que te lo busque. Por eso el error dice que es `null`, porque no lo defines bien y no puede encontrarlo. Tienes esas dos opciones :D